# For loop with byte counter hangs at start

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loops, for-loop

This a very simple for loop:

```
for (byte i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
{
    //do something
}
```

the loop after i becomes 0 the loop hangs until visual studio finally stops running, but why?

If I change the counter type to int it works perfectly.

Comment: @ remove do something and run it as: `for (byte i = 0; i <= 255; i++);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your byte is overflowing at 255. If you print `i` in the loop like this:

```
for (byte i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

You will see an output like this:

```
...
253
254
255
0
1
...
```

The maximum value of a byte is 255 so `i <= 255` can never become false. Change your condition to `i < 255` to solve the infinite loop.

Answer (score 9):

That's because the expression `i <= 255` is always true for a byte. As `255` is the highest value that can be stored in a byte, there is no value that could make the expression false.

When increasing the value `255` it will overflow and become `0`.

Comment: I thought of overflow but I expected an error like throwing an exception

Comment: @Failure: An overflow will not cause an exception by default, you can use the [`checked` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) to enforce overflow checks.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `i <= 255` only makes sense if `i` can have a value bigger than 255. When `i == 255` the loop body executes, then `i` is incremented. Notionally its value is 256, but that is bigger than can be stored in a byte, so its value is truncated (think of addition modulo 256) and becomes zero. This is still less than 255 so the loop runs again.